# Error al conectar app nodejs con mysql usando xampp en mac osCatalina

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express, xampp

Cuando ejecuto por consola `node app.js` me tira el siguiente error:

```
 ✘ german@MacBook-Air-de-Apple  ~/Desktop/UTN/Modulo3/Unidad-4/mysqlexpress  node app
Servidor escuchando en puerto 3000
/Users/german/Desktop/UTN/Modulo3/Unidad-4/mysqlexpress/app.js:20
        throw error;
        ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/german/Desktop/UTN/Modulo3/Unidad-4/mysqlexpress/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/german/Desktop/UTN/Modulo3/Unidad-4/mysqlexpress/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/Users/german/Desktop/UTN/Modulo3/Unidad-4/mysqlexpress/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/german/Desktop/UTN/Modulo3/Unidad-4/mysqlexpress/app.js:18:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}
```

El código de conexión es el siguiente:

```javascript
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const util = require('util');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.use(express.json()); // permite el mapeo de la peticion json a object js

// Conexion con mysql
const conexion = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'listacompras',

});

conexion.connect((error) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }

  console.log('Conexion con la base de datos mysql establecida');
});

const qy = util.promisify(conexion.query).bind(conexion);
```

Comment: Dices que el servidor escucha en el puerto 3000, pero el ECONNREFUSED menciona la puerta 3006 ... ???

Comment: ¿Verificaste que el servidor `MySQL` este corriendo? ¿Estas seguro de que activates al usuario `root` para poder conectarte (_[por defecto no puede](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)_)?

Answer (score 0):

Estoy revisando el código y te sobra una coma al final de donde defines la info de la base de datos, es decir , donde pone database name al final te sobra la coma!!

```
const conexion = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'listacompras', //<--AQUI

});
```